# Binding anonymous type to Create a BindingList

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a BindingList<> from anonymous type returned by LINQ query but BindingList<> do not accept anonymous type, following is my code

```
var data = context.RechargeLogs.Where(t => t.Time >= DateTime.Today).
           Select(t => new 
           {
                col1 = t.Id,
                col2 = t.Compnay,
                col3 = t.SubscriptionNo,
                col4 = t.Amount,
                col5 = t.Time
           });

var tmp =  new BindingList<???>(data);
```

In the last line generic argument what to place ???

Answer (score 9):

You can write an extension method:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(this IList<T> source)
    {
        return new BindingList<T>(source);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
        var query = entities
            .Select(e => new
            {
               // construct anonymous entity here
            })
            .ToList()
            .ToBindingList();
```

Comment: Nice one bro. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use this object in other places, I would suggest either using `dynamic`, or even better, to simply create the object you need as a `struct`.

```
public class RechargeLogData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionNo { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}

var data = context.RechargeLogs.Where(t => t.Time >= DateTime.Today).
       Select(t => new RechargeLogData()
       {
            Id = t.Id,
            Company = t.Compnay,
            SubscriptionNo = t.SubscriptionNo,
            Amount = t.Amount,
            Time = t.Time
       });

var tmp =  new BindingList<RechargeLogData>(data);
```

Comment: i m going go bind this source to datagrid, when i update RechargeLog, datagrid would not update i think

Comment: Have you tried it? Updating the `DataGrid` seems like a different question. Please feel free to open a new one and we can help you.

Comment: -1 for the mutable struct with fields. Binding engines don't work with fields. Value types shouldn't be considered as direct replacement for reference types. Structs **must be** immutable.

Answer (score -1):

The lowest common base type your data shares. For example object if thats the case.

```
var tmp =  new BindingList<object>(data);
```